Compiling (with pdflatex) twice a document from the terminal
Can I compile (with pdflatex) twice a document from the terminal?
I am looking for a command such as:
pdflatex -number-of-compilation 2 my_document.tex


you could use arara or latexmk or a similar tool. or you could use the facilities of whatever shell you use in your terminal either on-the-fly or you could make a function or alias.

If you are familiar enough, you can also use make, but I wouldn't recommend looking to that if it is unfamiliar. There is also (on Unix-like systems) something as simple as pdflatex mydoc.tex ; pdflatex mydoc.tex.

Why only two times? Better two hundreds times with pauses of  two seconds to avoid CPU overheating:  for run in {1..200}; do pdflatex foo.tex; sleep 2;  done. Well, seriously: Compilation often involve also  other programs depending on what you have (bibliography, indexes or glossaries, ...) and just  a option of -n 2  times wouldn't be of much help.  Better use latexmk, tectonic,  rubber, arara, o just a custom simple script if you know  the right order of the commands.

pdflatex my_document; pdflatex mydocument is the usual way, but surely that isn't the answer to your are looking for?

I see no reason for doing this. Yes, in some cases running LaTeX twice will remove a “Labels may have changed” message, but the important thing is that no such message appears at the glorious final typesetting when the document is ready for publication.

@DavidCarlisle Yes it is! My knowledge of terminal is quite low… You can add it as an answer!

but normally I wouldn;t use ; I'd just run the command twice so type pdflatex my_document hit reurun then if I want to run it again hit uparrow return to re-run the last command, or just type pdflatex my_document again/

This issue is that I have I have 7 documents and that each document takes 10 minutes to compile and that, to be sure, I compile 3 times…

@Colas If your document take long to compile, don't compile them unnecessarily often. Use an automation tool like latexmk to determine how many compilations are necessary. If you need more fine control, use arara and define the criteria for recompiling yourself.

pdflatex my_document; pdflatex mydocument <return>

would be the usual way if you really need to do it on one line ; is a commnd separator in many shells.
But I wouldn't normally do that I'd just do
pdflatex mydocument <return>

then if I need to do a second run, either type that again or (in bash or windows commandlines at least) hit <up-arrow> to recall the previous command and <return> to run it again.

Why wouldn’t you usually do that?

typing pdflatex my_document; pdflatex mydocument means correctly typing 41 characters and if there is an error in the document you get every error twice which is rather pointless. typing pdflatex mydocument only requires typing 20 characters and if there is an error you don't run again and if you do run again uparrow return is just two keystrokes. So the first form is twice as much  to type and has no advantages. @Colas
